# How to find NSDate in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsdate

I get seconds value from my function. For example I got: 22'356 seconds. Now I want to **subtract** this value from **now** and get `NSDate`, How can I achieve it?

Also, I have a function:

```
let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow:time.doubleValue)
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
self.lastSeenText = "last seen on \(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date))"
```

but this function **adds** difference to **now**. For example, if difference is 2 days, and today is 12.10.15, it will print 14.10.15.

How can I get opposite value, 10.10.15?

Comment: Subtracting a number `x` is the same as adding `-x` ...

Comment: @MartinR Unary operator '-' cannot be applied to an operand of type 'UInt'

Comment: Which means that you did not show your real code. Or is `time.doubleValue` an  `UInt` ??

Comment: Yes, it's UInt @MartinR

Comment: We cannot know how it is defined because you did not show the definition. But defining a property `doubleValue` which has the type `UInt` is at least very misleading for every reader of your code.

Comment: @MartinR so you can ask me to add more lines of code, instead of minus my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use minus symbol before `time.doubleValue`;

```
let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow:-time.doubleValue)
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
self.lastSeenText = "last seen on \(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date))"
```

Comment: That won't work if `time.doubleValue` is a UInt - as stated in the comments of the question.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
let datenow = NSDate()
let twoDays: NSTimeInterval = 2*24*60*60
let date = datenow.dateByAddingTimeInterval(-twoDays)
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
let lastSeenText = "last seen on \(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date))"
```

Comment: Unary operator '-' cannot be applied to an operand of type 'UInt'

Comment: I've test it on my computer, everything is successfull

Comment: the problem is that my `timeInSeconds` is UInt, not NSTimeInterval

Comment: then cast it to NSTimeInterval

Comment: You cant count on that every day has 24 hours. You should use date by adding calendar unit .Day

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow:time.doubleValue)
```

To this:

```
let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: -NSTimeInterval(time.doubleValue))
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the following..

```
let datenow = NSDate()
let twoDays: NSTimeInterval = 2*24*60*60
let date = datenow.dateByAddingTimeInterval(-twoDays)
print(date)
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
let lastSeenText = "last seen on \(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date))"
print(lastSeenText)
```

Comment: why minus vote on this? I have tested this on my xcode.